# How to make daemon --stop blocking until underlying process will die?

Tags: bash, signals, daemon

I have a java process daemonized using `daemon` command (RHEL 6.2). I'm using following line to start the process and the line below to stop it:

```
daemon --command "/opt/my-service" --respawn --name=my-service --verbose
daemon --stop --name=my-service --verbose
```

Things work until I'll try to restart my process using stop/start approach:

```
daemon --stop --name=my-service --verbose
daemon --command "/opt/my-service" --respawn --name=my-service --verbose
```

It the process is running before the above command is executed, then existing process will be stopped but then new one will not be created. Instead, following line will be logged to the `/var/log/messages`:

> `Oct 27 07:59:46 myhostname my-service: my-service: fatal: failed to become a daemon: Resource temporarily unavailable`

which as far as I understand means that we tried to acquire lock on the pid file but another process was holding the lock on it. Or in the other words: the original process was still running.

What is interesting it can not be reproduced by i.e. following command:

```
daemon --command "sleep 30s" --respawn --name=sleeper --verbose
daemon --stop --name=sleeper --verbose
daemon --command "sleep 30s" --respawn --name=sleeper --verbose
```

then there must be something in my process which causes/exploits asynchronous nature of `--stop`.

How can I make `--stop` blocking?

Comment: Have you tried: `daemon --name=my-service --running` ?

Comment: I haven't tried. Do you mean that I could write a loop which would run until the process has died (with some timeout) and then start the process back?

Comment: Well, i could not reproduce the behaviour of your java application, but yes, try somethign like ... I'll post it as solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
while true; do
  daemon --name=my-service --running --verbose | grep not
  [ $? -eq 0 ] && exit
  sleep 1
done
```

Description as p-code:
forever {
  check if `daemon --name=my-service --running --verbose` returns some thing containing the word `not`
  if yes, `exit`
  otherwise `sleep a second`
}

Comment: Thanks. I'll adjust it to timeout after few seconds.

Comment: Don't use `grep`. `daemon --running` provides an exit status, so you can just equivalently write: `while daemon --name=my-server --running; do sleep 1; done`